# Dart changing a variable value using own extension method

Tags: android, flutter, dart, native, extension-methods

I was trying to delete elements of a list using my own extension but I got an error. This error says the extension is only readable.

This is my extension

```
extension ToListExtention on List {
  List toDatatable() {
    List columns = [];
    List rows = [];
    (this.first as Map).forEach((key, value) {columns.add(key);});
    this.forEach((element) {
      rows.add((element as Map).values);
    });
    **this.clear();**
    return [columns,rows];
  }
}
```

and this is the error that I got

```
E/flutter (24973): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: read-only
E/flutter (24973): #0      QueryResultSet.length= (package:sqflite_common/src/collection_utils.dart:109:5)
E/flutter (24973): #1      ListMixin.clear (dart:collection/list.dart:342:10)
E/flutter (24973): #2      ToListExtention.toDatatable (package:dbdeneme/Extentions.dart:9:10)
E/flutter (24973): #3      _AnasayfaState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dbdeneme/main.dart:58:27)
E/flutter (24973): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (24973): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (24973): <asynchronous suspension>
```

So, as you understand, the bolded line doesn't work. How can I do it inside my own extension?

Comment: It depends on the `List`. Some `List` objects are protected from changes e.g. `const` lists or if the `List` has not been defined to be `growable` (since we are then not allowed to change its size). In your case, the `List` is actually a read-only list, which means operations, which changes the list, are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In extensions, you cannot change the original value of the object.
You can copy the list and then do all kinds of manipulation on that list. But you cannot change the list.

Comment: Wrong. You can change the content of the list in an extension method as long as you are following the rules for that list (e.g. it must be e.g. growable if you want to change its size).

Comment: I created a list using List.generate and I set the growable parameter as True, but it didn't work. What else rule I have to follow ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the list you are calling `toDatatable` on is a `QueryResultSet` which implementation can be found here:
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/81c0c30aa59d7d3f229bf6ce0494458f96f893c2/sqflite_common/lib/src/collection_utils.dart#L74

Which implements `length` (called by `clear()`) with the following:

```
  @override
  set length(int newLength) {
    throw UnsupportedError('read-only');
  }
```

So your current extension method are not going to work on this kind of `List` (`List` are just an interface in this case and `QueryResultSet` are implementing that interface).